# what is the use of AND with ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

What does the AND do in a query like so

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE SaleNo > 200,
ORDER BY EmployeeNo AND SaleNo;
```

How is it different from

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE SaleNo > 200,
ORDER BY EmployeeNo, SaleNo;
```

Both queries actually return a table back but I don't understand the meaning of 1st query.
ORDER BY is usually used along with pipes and commas for additional filterings. TIA

Comment: AND is not used in ORDER BY clause. It can be used in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY EmployeeNo AND SaleNo;
```

The above becomes this:

```
ORDER BY (EmployeeNo AND SaleNo)
```

And then becomes:

```
ORDER BY (true/false AND true/false)
```

And then

```
ORDER BY (true/false)
```

So the expression is converted to a true/false expression.

If the 2 columns are number types, then 
    0 values = false, and any NON zero value = true

so, you have

```
  ORDER BY ( (EmployeeNo <> 0) AND (SaleNo <> 0) )
```

So, if both EmplyeeNo and SaleNo have a value?

You get this

```
  ORDER BY ( (true) AND (True))

  ORDER BY True
```

The value is thus -1.

What this means is that if both values have a number, (not 0), then they will appear first in the list and all others if one of the two numbers are 0 or both are 0 will follow.

So, to order by a column, and then by a anohter, you use

```
col1, col2  - as you have.
```

if  you go

```
col1 AND col2
```

Then this is  Boolean (true/false) expression, and not a order by one column, and then on to the next.